# How do I list a directory with php to navigate through folders, without javascript?

Tags: php, treeview, tree, navigation, directory

I am looking for this PHP function:

- List a directory, recursive
- The functionallity to navigate through folders
- No javascript
- Navigation via web adress, "?p=2|1" or something like that
- Sorted by type then names

Comment: this is a huge question. You will get better responses by breaking it down into components. (how do I list the contents of a folder?, how can I change the working directory using an anchor tag? etc etc...)

Comment: Just to get the url paging to work with directory tree listing would be a key. The rest may be easier to resolve.

Comment: This is not a "make me a PHP application" website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
class DirTree
{
    protected $root;
    protected $active;
    const URL_KEY = 'el';

    public function __construct($root, $active = null) {
        $this->root = realpath($root);

        if ($active !== null) {
            $this->active = realpath($this->root . '/' . $active);
        }
    }

    public function isActive($element) {
        return substr($this->active, 0, strlen($element->getPathname())) === $element->getPathname();
    }

    public function getLink($element) {
        return '?' . http_build_query(array(
            self::URL_KEY => substr($element->getPathname(), strlen($this->root))
        ));
    }

    protected function _get(Iterator $it) {
        $result = array();

        $dirs = $files = array();
        foreach ($it as $entry) {
            if ($entry->isDir()) {
                $data = (object)array(
                    'type' => 'dir',
                    'name' => $entry->getBasename(),
                    'object' => $entry
                );

                if ($this->isActive($entry)) {
                    $data->children = $this->_get($it->getChildren());
                    $data->active = true;
                }

                $dirs[$entry->getBasename()] = $data;
            }
            else {
                $files[$entry->getFilename()] = (object)array(
                    'type' => 'file',
                    'name' => $entry->getFilename(),
                    'object' => $entry,
                    'active' => $this->isActive($entry)
                );
            }
        }

        uksort($dirs, 'strnatcmp');
        uksort($files, 'strnatcmp');

        return array_values(array_merge($dirs, $files));
    }

    public function get() {
        return $this->_get(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->root)
        );
    }

    public function outputUl($dirTree = null) {
        if ($dirTree === null) {
            $dirTree = $this->get();
        }

        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($dirTree as $element) {
            $classes = array($element->type);

            if ($element->type === 'dir') {
                if ($element->active) {
                    $classes[] = 'active';
                }

                echo '<li class="', implode(' ', $classes), '">';
                echo '<a href="', $this->getLink($element->object),'">';
                echo $element->name;
                echo '</a>';
                if (sizeof($element->children) > 0) {
                    $this->outputUl($element->children);
                }
                echo '</li>';
            }
            else {
                if ($element->active) {
                    $classes[] = 'active';
                }           

                echo '<li class="', implode(' ', $classes), '">';
                echo '<a href="', $this->getLink($element->object),'">';
                echo $element->name;
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }

        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>DirTree</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #dirTree a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #171717;
            }

            #dirTree .file a {
                color: #999999;
            }

            #dirTree .active > a {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="dirTree">
            <?php
                $dirTree = new DirTree(
                    '.',
                     isset($_GET[DirTree::URL_KEY]) ? $_GET[DirTree::URL_KEY] : null
                );
                $dirTree->outputUl();
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Yoshi Yes, but I want the parents to be visible the whole time.

Comment: @Peter See the update, it's still a lot to do though. But I think it's enough as an example.

Comment: @Yoshi Impressing. So small code, so much functionallity. To bad I don't understand everything by my self. But it's a nice feeling to get a functionally code that behave as I wanted. After sevral days of confusion. "RecursiveDirectoryIterator" must be some built-in php class?

Comment: @Peter Yes, it comes with SPL, have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php

Comment: @Yoshi how do I get `printf('<li><a href="?dir=%s/%2$s">%2$s</a>', implode('/', $parents), $entry->getBasename());` to be a echo instead? Want the code to be little more understandable to myself.

Comment: @Peter See the updated example. You can use string concatenation. Also I tend to find printf (http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) more readable ;)

Comment: @Yoshi I would like to be able to click on the files as well. I've tried to modify the code but failed. I tried: `echo '<li>(file) <a href="?dir='.$entry->getPathname().'">'.$entry->getFilename().'</a></li>';`

Comment: @Peter what do you want to happen when someone clicks a file? Do you want to directly link him/her to that file?

Comment: @Yoshi No, the file name should just be marked as selected, like with a .sel style class or something.

Comment: @Yoshi `printf(
                '<li><a href="?dir=%s/%s"%s>%s</a></li>',
                implode('/', $parents),
                $entry->getFilename(),
                $activeDir === $entry->getPathname() ? 'class="active"' : '',
                $entry->getFilename()
            );
` wont work

Comment: @Peter See the updated code. Hope it helps. ;)

Comment: @Yoshi I need the whole path in the GET statement. The root is dynamic based on the path in the url. So I can use it like this: `$dirTree = new DirTree(
     './archive/'.$this_category
   , '/'.$dir_to_current_file
   );
   $dirTree->outputUl();`

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to make something like it, so here is a function that does exactly that. Optionally, you can add classnames to files and folders to style them with CSS.
All folders are displayed 'opened', although with a little JS you can make a function to add some 'open-close' behaviour to the list.

```
<?php
/**
 * function makeDirectoryTree
 * iterates recursively through a directory
 * and lists it in an unordered list
 * 
 * usage: echo makeDirectoryTree(relative/path/to/directory);
 * 
 * @param string $pathname
 * @return string
 */
function makeDirectoryTree($pathname){
   $path = realpath($pathname);

   if(!is_dir($path)){
      return "Path does not exist!";
   }

   $foldertree = new DOMDocument();

   /*
    * the rootelement of the tree 
    */
   $ul[""] = $foldertree->createElement('ul');
   $ul[""]->setAttribute('id', 'foldertree_root');
   $foldertree->appendChild($ul[""]);

   /*
    * Files in rootfolder
    * if not iterated separately, these files will appear alphabetically between the folders
    * instead of on top of the list
    *
    */
   $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($path);
   foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
      if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
         /*
          * the random id could be useful if you want to manipulate an element with JS
          * for instance to 'open' or 'close' the folders
          * also, add an optional classname to files and folders, so you can
          * do some markup with CSS, for instance:
          * .folder {color: #f00; list-style-image: url('path/to/images/folder.png');}
          * .file {color: #999; list-style-image: url('path/to/images/file.png');}
          */
         $random_id = md5(microtime());
         $li_element = $foldertree->createElement('li', $fileinfo->getFilename());
         $li_element->setAttribute('id', 'li_' . str_ireplace(' ', '', $random_id));
         $li_element->setAttribute('class', 'file'); //optional classname
         $ul[""]->appendChild($li_element);
      }
   }

   /*
    * iterate through the other folders
    */
   $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

   foreach($objects as $name=>$value){
      if($value->isDir()){
         $relative_path = str_ireplace($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "", $value->getPathname());
         $path_array = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $relative_path);

         $new_dir = array_pop($path_array);
         $directory_up = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path_array);

         $random_id = md5(microtime());

         $li[$relative_path] = $foldertree->createElement('li', $new_dir);
         $li[$relative_path]->setAttribute('id', 'li_' . str_ireplace(' ', '', $random_id));
         $li[$relative_path]->setAttribute('class', 'folder'); //optional classname

         $ul[$relative_path] = $foldertree->createElement('ul');
         $ul[$relative_path]->setAttribute('id', 'ul_' . str_ireplace(' ', '', $random_id));

         $li[$relative_path]->appendChild($ul[$relative_path]);
         $ul[$directory_up]->appendChild($li[$relative_path]);

         $iterator = new DirectoryIterator($value->getPathname());
         foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
            if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
               $random_id = md5(microtime());
               $li_element = $foldertree->createElement('li', $fileinfo->getFilename());
               $li_element->setAttribute('id', 'li_' . str_ireplace(' ', '', $random_id));
               $li_element->setAttribute('class', 'file'); //optional classname
               $ul[$relative_path]->appendChild($li_element);
            }
         }
      }
   }

   return $foldertree->saveHTML();
}
?>
```

Comment: But the thing is that I **don't** want to use JS. And I don't want all folders to be displayed as opened.

Comment: I forgot your name in the prevoius comment. Don't know if that matters... Would like som help.

Comment: @Peter no problem, how can I help?