# Recursive menu tree function

Tags: php, recursion, wordpress

This snippet displays a menu tree of pages and the current pages children for up to two levels. How can I make this recursive to work for unlimited levels?

```
if( empty($wp_query->post->post_parent) ) {
    $parent = $wp_query->post->ID;
} else {
    $parent = $wp_query->post->post_parent;
} ?>
<?php if(wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=0" )): ?>
<div id="submenu">
    <ul>
    <?php wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent" ); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `This snippet displays a menu tree` - I don't see any tree-like behaviour here - it looks just be listing the children of the post's parent if it has one or this posts children if not. I would expect to see some form of loop or recursive function call to display a tree... is there more code that wraps this that you show us?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881335/how-do-i-list-a-directory-with-php-to-navigate-through-folders-without-javascri/5883362#5883362

Comment: @DaveRandom Sorry if the question is unclear but the snippet does not properly parse a tree (only up to two levels) so that is what I need help to figure out.

Comment: @Joseph Can you show the query used to populate `$wp_query`?

Comment: [I'll just leave this here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors)

Comment: Give an example of what you want this menu to look like and ill whip up a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?
function getParent($obj){
  if (empty($obj->post->post_parent)){
    return $obj->post->ID;
  } else {
    return getParent($obj->post->post_parent);
  }
}
$parent = getParent($wp_query)
?>
```