# List o paths to hierarchical array

Tags: php, arrays, hierarchical-data

I have a serialized data with a list of filepaths each one with or without one or more files inside.

```
array
  0 => 'config.ini'
  1 => 'folder/file1.php'
  2 => 'folder/folder2/file2.php'
  3 => 'folder/folder2/folder3/file3.php'
  4 => 'folder/folder2/folder3/file4.php'
```

> The first one is in the root folder, outside any subdirectory

And I would like to convert this array into a multidimensional hierarchical array, being **folder3** a sub-array of **folder2** and this a sub-array of **folder1**.

With [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4904365/753531) I almost succeeded. The problem is, because it was created for a different purpose, with my array the files (wit extensions) are also being considered as more dimensions, instead of being appended as values of the last entry. E.g: *file3.php* and *file4.php* should be **values** of *folder3*, not indexes.

I tried to modify it by myself but reference is one of the few features I don't understand in PHP.

If worth to mention, I'm converting this structure to build a Treeview.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881335/how-do-i-list-a-directory-with-php-to-navigate-through-folders-without-javascri

Comment: No, not this topic in particular, but this structure was built with *RecursiveDirectoryIterator* and although I could built it hierarchically from start, it's hard to compute differences with a multidimensional structure, specially when the second array is not one and can't be because it comes from a parsed INI file (which can't be defined hierarchically - I tried). I don't really need this feature, it's just something nice to have in my edit form page.